# Conjecture about the Jordan-Polya numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, factorial, conjectures

The Jordan-Polya numbers are the products of factorial numbers [A001013](http://oeis.org/A001013):

```
1,2,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,36,48,64,72,96,120,128,144,192,216,240,256,288,384,432,480,512,576,720,768,864,960,1024,1152,1296,1440,1536,1728,1920,2048,2304,2592,2880,3072,3456,3840,4096,4320,4608,5040,5184,5760,...
```

It seems that the difference between two consecutive Jordan-Polya numbers itself is a Jordan-Polya number. Is this true and if so, are there a proof of this somewhere?

Comment: @Lens:  What have you tried?  As the guidelines on this site state, it is important that you show your work.  You're far more likely to get assistance that way... and it helps us know *what* you don't understand or haven't tried.  And in trying, you might solve the problem yourself... which is of course ideal.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - I have no idea how to proceed on this. There are no explicit formula for the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false.  Using the data in your list...

$$  4320 - 4096 = 224  \text{.}  $$

The next few violations of the conjecture are:
\begin{align*}
8192 - 7776 &= 416  \text{,}  \\
8640 - 8192 &= 448  \text{,}  \\
16384 - 15552 &= 832  \text{,}  \\
17280 - 16384 &= 896  \text{, and}  \\ 
25920 - 24576 &= 1344  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
So, while it is common in the first few instances that violations include a power of $2$, this is not true for all violations.

There are $6853$ Jordan-Polya numbers up to $20!$.  Computing the gaps and splitting up the first $6800$ gaps into blocks of $100$ gaps ("centuries").  We plot the number of gaps conforming with the conjecture.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After initial high levels of conformance, by the tenth century (thousandth gap), the likelihood of a Jordan-Polya number gap being a Jordan-Polya number seems to be around $50\%$ and is, at least for the range covered, fairly stably so.

Repeating up to $30!$, there are $91\,802$ Jordan-Polya numbers and $53\,065$ gaps are violating.  The plot by centuries ...
[image: Mathematica graphics]
... suggests that conforming instances become rarer as one proceeds.

Comment: Thanks! Do you use the table from OEIS?

Comment: @Lehs : No.  Generated my own tables using the Mathematica code at the OEIS.

Comment: Okay! I designed my own algorithm  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930578/an-algorithm-testing-jordan-polya-numbers to get a second opinion and I am now convinced that the conjecture is false. :)