# An algorithm for testing "Jordan - Polya" numbers?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, factorial

A *Jordan-Polya* number is a number that can be factorized with factorials (i.e., $240=2!\cdot5!$) and I'm searching for an algorithm to test the property of being a *Jordan-Polya* number.

Obviously, the factorial of the largest prime factor $p$ of $n$ must divide $n$ if $n$ is a JP-number. Therefore, the existence of a number $m$ such that $p\le m<p'$ where $n/m!$ is JP and $p'$ is the successor prime of $p$, should be a necessary and sufficient condition.

I've tried to use this to construct the divide-and-conquer algorithm below, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
1. Function IsJp(input numb) boolean
2. if IsFactorial(numb) then return true
3.    prime ← LargestPrimeFactor(numb)
4.      for i = prime to NextPrime(prime) - 1
5.         if (numb mod i!) = 0 then return IsJp(numb / i!) 
6.             next i
7.  return false
```

When running in Forth there is trouble with a return stack overflow. So what is wrong? How can I correct the algorithm?

**Edit**: I think I found the problem: there should be a terminal case for failure in the beginning of the algorithm:

```
1. Function IsJp(input numb) boolean
2. if IsFactorial(numb) then return true
3.   if IsPrime(numb) then return false
4.     prime ← LargestPrimeFactor(numb)
5.       for i = prime to NextPrime(prime) - 1
6.          if (numb mod i!) = 0 then return IsJp(numb / i!) 
7.              next i
8.  return false
```

**Edit**:

```
1. Function IsJp(input numb) boolean
2. if IsFactorial(numb) then return true
3.   if IsPrime(numb) then return false
4.     prime ← LargestPrimeFactor(numb)
5.       for i = NextPrime(prime) - 1 to prime step -1
6.          if (numb mod i!) = 0 then 
7.             if IsJp(numb / i!) then return true
8.                next i
9.  return false
```

This algorithm is tested with all 64-bit numbers in the table of the first 10,000 jp-numbers on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001013/b001013.txt).

**Edit**:

```
1. Function IsJp(input numb) boolean
2. if IsFactorial(numb) then return true
3.     prime ← LargestPrimeFactor(numb)
4.       for i = NextPrime(prime) - 1 to prime step -1
5.          if (numb mod i!) = 0 then 
6.             if IsJp(numb / i!) then return true
7.                next i
8.  return false
```

A row was deleted, since not needed.

Comment: the first thing to check is that the prime factors are consecutive beginning with 2, with non-increasing exponents. That is, such a number must be $$  2^a 3^b 5^c 7^d 11^e \cdots $$ with integers $$ a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq e \geq \cdots \geq 1$$  Once that is confirmed, I imagine there are techniques from optimization for constructing a factoring by factorials or confirming that such is impossible. In essence, I see each factorial as a vector of exponents up to the largest prime needed, then finding a nonnegative sum of these  that sum up to the vector of exponents your target number

Comment: alright, given several exponent vectors $f_i$ of factorials, up tp $(q-1)!$ where $q$ is the first prime not present in your target, you can just do a brute force search for $\sum a_i f_i = T,$ where each integer $a_i \geq 0$ and $T$ is the exponent vector of the target.

Comment: @WillJagy - is my approach useless?

Comment: The logic seems to be correct, however I think the "it doesn't work" needs to be given by example. Also, syntactically *if numb(mod i!)=0* should be *if (numb mod i!)=0*, no? And the recursive function call misses the output parameter. So it might be an issue with the actual implementation.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó - How does the recursive function call misses the output parameter? Recursion makes me confused...

Comment: Why do you need an *output* at all? You don't assign a value to *flag* anywhere in the function body. Of course this might not be the source of the main issue.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó - The value following 'return' is supposed to represent the value of flag.

Comment: OK, then it's fine for me.

Comment: "stack overflow" happens when the memory runs out that was assigned to the function to use during running (the stack) See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). The outer function has a non-dynamic memory space, however depending on the depth of recursion, the amount of memory used is quite dynamic. You might need to re-write it as a non-recursive algorithm, but I don't know Forth.

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on a coding website?